# Can cause/lead be followed by a that clause?

Tags: word-usage

What I want to know is if lead or cause can be followed by a that clause？

> The shortage of this item will cause/lead that the production cannot be on schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a that-clause after **lead to** or **cause**. For verbs where you can use a that-clause, this is clearly documented in a good dictionary- for example the word **think** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/think).

You cannot use "cannot be on schedule" in this sentence: you should simply say "not be on schedule". This is grammatically correct but not very elegant. It would be more natural to say "fall behind schedule" or "be delayed" or "run late" or "a delay".

Both **lead to** and **cause** can both be followed by a simple object:

> The shortage of this item will cause a production delay
>   The shortage of this item will lead to a production delay

With **cause**, you just use a simple infinitive for a verb:

> The shortage of this item will cause production to fall behind schedule
>   The shortage of this item will cause production to be delayed
>   The shortage of this item will cause production to run late

With **lead to**, you have to use a gerund (-ing):

> The shortage of this item will lead to production falling behind schedule
>   The shortage of this item will lead to production being delayed
>   The shortage of this item will lead to production running late